# Which romanization system is closest to native pronunciation of Standard Mandarin?

Tags: pronunciation, chinese, transliteration

The most commonly used Mandarin romanization systems are [Hanyu Pinyin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanyu_Pinyin) (most common by far), [Gwoyeu Romatzyh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gwoyeu_Romatzyh) (GR), and [Wade-Giles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wade%E2%80%93Giles) (more common in Taiwan than China). Based on your experience, and regardless of the system's popularity, does one of these romanization systems do a better job than others of helping Mandarin students correctly pronounce standard Mandarin (tones, consonants, and a vowels)?

Comment: Are you sure that Wade-Giles is used at all in Taiwan? By native speakers of Mandarin / Standard Chinese? Or was that parenthesis mean to be placed after "Gwoyeu Romatzyh"?

Comment: Yes, Wade-Giles, among other systems, is used in Taiwan to some degree. Pinyin dominates everywhere though.

Comment: Is the native language of the students relevant here, and if yes, are you interested in a particular one?

Comment: The student's native language does not make a difference to me in this case; any L1 learning Mandarin as an L2.